# Java - Date Format converter?

Tags: java, date, date-format

Has java any function where I have a String with a date in this form : `ddMMyy` or `dd.MM.yy`
and I want to convert it in another format like: `dd:MM:yy`

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Despite its name, [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) both parses and formats dates and times.

Comment: some code would be nice :)

Comment: @InfernoVol Some [searching before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+date+format) would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using two SimpleDateFormat objects for this.

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy").parse( dateString);
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yy").format( date );
```

For the format, see the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: some code would be nice :)

Comment: oh nice, gracias  :)